# Check password strength against an API value

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-mobile

I get my password spec from an API which then I split the object into the needed fields and check that I have the required number of lower, upper, special and length of my password.

```
    function isStrong(passwordChecker) {

    if (!passwordChecker) {
        return false;
    }

    debugger;
    var securityOption = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("Security"));

    var MinLength = securityOption.PasswordMinRequiredLength;
    var SpecialChars = securityOption.PasswordMinRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters;
    var MinLowercase = securityOption.PasswordMinRequiredLowercase;
    var MinUppercase = securityOption.PasswordMinRequiredUppercase;

    //LenghtCheck
    if (passwordChecker.length < MinLength);
        return false;

    if (!CountSpecialChars(passwordChecker) > SpecialChars) {
        return false;
    }

    if (MinLowercase > 0) {
        if (!CountLowerCase(passwordChecker) > MinLowercase) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    if (MinUppercase > 0) {
        if (!CountUpperCase(passwordChecker) > MinLowercase) {
            return false;
        }
    }    
}

function CountSpecialChars(text) {
    var Count = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
        var c = text[i];

        if (text[i] >= 33 && text[i] <= 63){
            Count++;
        }        
    }
}

function MinLowercase(text) {
    var Count = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
        var c = text[i];
        if (text[i] >= 97 && text[i] <= 122) {
            Count++;
        }
    }
}

function MinUppercase(text) {
    var Count = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
        var c = text[i];
        if (text[i] >= 65 && text[i] <= 90) {
            Count++;
        }
    }
}
```

Now what I want to do is, check the different conditions as a whole and if all of the conditions are true then change the class to green..

```
        $(pageId + ' #password').bind('keyup', function () {
        var currentpassword = $(pageId + ' #password').val();
        if (isStrong(currentpassword)) {
            $(pageId + ' #password').addClass('green');

        } else {
            $(pageId + ' #password').addClass('red');
        }

    });
```

I am not sure how to check the conditions as a whole and return an overall true because as I start trying in my password it instantly changes to green as in my password spec you do not need any UpperCase or LowerCase letters so on any input of a char it returns true..

Comment: Use a bitmask and set each bit to 1 if a specific condition is met, then check if all bits are set

Comment: @Anthony I will have to do some research on bitmask - have never heard of it before..

Comment: as a side remark, it would be wise to have a more semantic css class naming. For example, your green and red classes would be better named "valid" and "invalid" for example, then in your CSS you specify the color. Why ? Because if you ever want to let's say use orange text for invalid password, you shouldn't have to change your HTML, only your CSS (you're changing only the color, this should be a CSS only thing), and in this case you would end up with a element with class  "red" which ends up being orange text. It's just nitpicking with this small example, but that's definitely a best-practice

Comment: Sorry, that was a geeky solution. Basically, you should change your functions like `CountLowerCase` so that they accept the string and the parameter and return true or false, then when you want to check all, you just have a function that runs all of them and sees if all are true.

Comment: @Bartdude Yeah I understand you completely, I should change it accordingly you are right. I'm just for now focusing on getting the condition to change on it's own.. I need to validate the complete input password before it changes the class(CSS)

Comment: @Anthony So make a big nested IF and then right at the bottom if all are true then pass back to my checker a true bool

Comment: yeah that was really on the side remark, but I'm sometimes a semantic-nazi :-)

Comment: @Anthony Could I not structure it so that if that certain IF passes the condition then move onto the next IF statement and so on until it has gone through them all then only returns TRUE?

Comment: You would want each to return true or false, then check if all return true. No need for nesting, just stop as soon as one returns false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should refactor your functions so that they accept both the string and the parameter and return true or false. For example:

```
function CountSpecialChars(text) {
    var Count = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
        var c = text[i];

        if (text[i] >= 33 && text[i] <= 63){
            Count++;
        }        
    }
}

if (!CountSpecialChars(passwordChecker) > SpecialChars) {
        return false;
    }
```

Should instead be:

```
function CountSpecialChars(text, min) {
    var count = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
        var c = text[i];

        if (text[i] >= 33 && text[i] <= 63){
            count++;
        }
    }

    return count > min;

}


return CountSpecialChars(passwordChecker, SpecialChars);
```

Also, as a bonus, you could also avoid that for loop for those functions by using `replace`, like so:

```
function MinChars(text, min) {

    return text.length > min;

}

function MinUppercase(text, min) {

    var non_uppers = /[^A-Z]/g;

    var uppers =  text.replace(non_uppers, text);

    return uppers.length > min;

}

function MinLowercase(text, min) {

    var non_lowers = /[^a-z]/g;

    var lowers =  text.replace(non_lowers, text);

    return lowers.length > min;

}

function MinSpecialChars(text, min) {

    var non_specials = /[^!-\?]/g;

    var specials =  text.replace(non_specials, text);

    return specials.length > min;

}
```

Now with those functions, you can have:

```
if !MinChars(pw, MinLength) return false;
if !MinSpecialChars(pw, SpecialChars) return false;
if !MinLowercase(pw, MinLowercase) return false;
if !MinUppercase(pw, MinUppercase) return false;
return true;
```

Comment: Ahh I see - hmmm so I will need to pass that to each function I understand that - then do an over all check